# C/C++ program not correctly works on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have written program, that sends 5 emails through my gmail adress, with 1 minute pause between. This program works on my laptop, but not works on Raspberry Pi. On Raspberry Pi it sends only 1 email.

main.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#include "email.c"

void threadFunction()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::string message = /*"Hello my name is Dmitry\r\nTest1\r\nTest2\r\n" + */std::to_string(i) + "\r\n";
        int status = sent_email("*********", "*********", "Test message", message.c_str(), "smtps://smtp.gmail.com", "*********", "*********");
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::minutes(1));
        status++;
    }
}

int main()
{
     /*std::thread thr(threadFunction);
     thr.join();*/
     threadFunction();
     return 0;
}
```

email.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

struct upload_information {
    const char *data;
    size_t data_length;
    size_t sent;
};

size_t read_callback(char *buffer, size_t size, size_t nitems, void *instream);

int sent_email(const char *FROM, const char *TO, const char *SUBJECT, const char *message, const char *server, const char *login, const char *password)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
    struct curl_slist *recipients = NULL;

    size_t length = strlen(message) + strlen(FROM) + strlen(TO) + strlen(SUBJECT) + 32; //32 is FROM: <>/n/r, TO: <>/n/r length and SUBJECT + new line(after header - SMTP standart) + /0

    char *data;
    data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * length);

    strcat(data, "FROM: <");
    strcat(data, FROM);
    strcat(data, ">\r\n");
    strcat(data, "TO: <");
    strcat(data, TO);
    strcat(data, ">\r\n");
    strcat(data, "SUBJECT: ");
    strcat(data, SUBJECT);
    strcat(data, "\r\n\r\n");
    strcat(data, message);

    struct upload_information upload_info;
    upload_info.data = data;
    upload_info.data_length = length;
    upload_info.sent = 0;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, login);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, password);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, server);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, FROM);
        recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, TO);
        //recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, CC);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_callback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &upload_info);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));

        curl_slist_free_all(recipients);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    free(data);
    return (int)res;
}

size_t read_callback(char *buffer, size_t size, size_t nitems, void *instream)
{
    struct upload_information *upload_info = (struct upload_information *)instream;

    if ((size == 0) || (nitems == 0) || (size * nitems < 1))
        return 0;

    if (upload_info->sent < upload_info->data_length)
    {
        size_t length = size * nitems;

        if (length > upload_info->data_length - upload_info->sent)
            length = upload_info->data_length - upload_info->sent;

        memcpy(buffer, upload_info->data + upload_info->sent, length);

        upload_info->sent += length;

        return length;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Error message on Raspberry Pi:
 
`*** glibc detected *** ./Mailer: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x01d0da38 ***`

P.S. Program on raspberry pi send 1 correct message and part of second message.
P.S.S Post was updated

Comment: Why do you spawn a thread when you could just call threadFunction directly?  Have you tried some good old printf debugging of your for loop?

Comment: Because in future will be more threads.

Comment: Well then try without the threading for  now and see if it works.  Basic troubleshooting: boil the problem down until it's simple, or goes away.

Comment: I have deleted thread, but it is still not working.

Comment: Suggesting running it under gdb and seeing where it falls appart. If that is too inconvenient, try printf-ing all return codes from curl plus some printf inside the for loop. Does it hang or does it finish in 5 mins but only 1 email sent?

Comment: You should change your password on the e-mail server. The password isn't in the (public) edit history, but someone might have been able to grab it during the brief period it was visible in the post.

Comment: Thank you, not noticed while updating post/

Comment: I can't see any issues that might be causing the new error. You should try to run it under a debugger and see if where it crashes gives you a clue as to what might have gotten corrupted, though it could've happened much earlier in the program. If that fails try running your application with valgrind, it should be able to tell you whats causes the errors. One I did notices that you need to call `curl_global_init` before you create any threads, but that should be fine since your example currently doesn't create any threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The buffer you're allocating for the message is 1 byte to short. The total length of all the constant strings you're adding is 29, but you also need to add one more byte for the `'\0'` character that `strcat` will terminate the string with.

If you run the following code it shows you that concatenated length of all the string literals is `30`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main() {
    printf("%d\n", (int) sizeof("FROM: <" ">\r\n"
                                "TO: <" ">\r\n"
                                "SUBJECT: " "\r\n"));
}
```

There are two other problem with the message. One is that you're not putting a blank line between the headers and the message as required. The other is that you're not terminating the final line of the message with `\r\n`. This might confuse the curl library as it will need to add the end of line terminator itself. If it doesn't the message won't be sent through SMTP correctly.

Comment: How the machines allocate memory is going to be very different, so your 1 byte buffer overrun might end up being harmless on the laptop. You might also be using a different version of the curl library on each machine. The version on your laptop might be better able to handle the missing blank line after the headers and/or the missing `\r\n` at the end.

Comment: Ok. And one more question. Why 1 email sends.

Comment: Anything could happen because of you buffer overflow. If the curl library doesn't the trailing `\r\n` it could get confused and stop sending messages. The STMP server might not like your malformed messages and reject further connections from you for a brief period.

Comment: I have corrected my code. Now it still correctly works on laptop. But on Raspberry Pi program crashes error. New code and error message are in my first message.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. Problem was because of when i freeв memory i am not reset memory.

I add `*data = '\0';` befor strcat.